# how to animate an image in flutter like https://youtu.be/vWgT_qla4gw

Tags: image, flutter, animation, background-image, uiviewanimation

I want to animate a background image like given in the video in flutter https://youtu.be/vWgT_qla4gw. please help me

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to animate the background but the popular one is to use animated_background library from pub.dev

[here's the link to it](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_background)

you can install this library to your flutter app and still can't figure out how to use it.....you can comeback here anytime.....cheers for your project